# Inteliji Idea does not recognize typescript

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, typescript

I use intellij Idea and try to run [example](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) of angularjs 2. I install all needed plugins (JavaScript Support and Node.js) but it seems that does not work for me. This is what I see:

[image]

Who knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have is in TypeScript 1.5. IntelliJ don't support it yet. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15585

Your only IDE options right now are MS tools (VS/VS Code) or sublime text.

Comment: Note that the latest EAP/preview release 141.1192.2 can already support decorators if you supply the 1.5 beta version externally in settings. The new module import syntax is still unsupported, but is supposedly fixed in WebStorm EAP. Hopefully the features get merged into IntelliJ soon.

Answer (score 1):

--edited, didn't read that well

The problem might be solved with switching to the right Javascript version -> http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/javascript-version-selector/

Comment: I installed all the necessary plug-ins (JavaScript Support and Node.js)

Comment: Then the problem might be solved with switching to the right Javascript version -> http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/javascript-version-selector/

Comment: Strange, works for me. Is Typescript listed in Settings -> Languages and Frameworks?

Comment: no, it there is not present... How can I add him to this list?

Comment: I think your on an older version then, I didn't have to install anything on IntelliJ 14 to get this working